# gst_rtsp_server does not stop

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gstreamer, rtsp

I am trying to make a tiny cpp program module that makes live stream from camera, I am using gstreamer1.0 and I have plugins 1.6 and gst-rtsp-server-1.6.0 . I am able to start stream but when I try to stop and start again it does not start again.
my pipeline is:

```
std_pipeline = "videotestsrc ! video/x-raw  ! "
                     "videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay"
```

and I am initializing with functions below:

```
gst_rtsp_server_new();
gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points(server);
gst_rtsp_media_factory_new();
gst_rtsp_media_factory_set_launch(factory, std_pipeline);
gst_rtsp_mount_points_add_factory(mounts, "/stream", factory);
gst_rtsp_server_attach(server, NULL);
```

to start stream I call in another thread:

```
g_main_loop_run(loop);
```

and I am try to destroy everything with:

```
GstRTSPSessionPool *pool
gst_rtsp_server_get_session_pool (server);
gst_rtsp_session_pool_filter (pool,
  (GstRTSPSessionPoolFilterFunc) remove_func, server);
g_object_unref (pool);
g_source_remove(server_id);
mounts = gst_rtsp_server_get_mount_points(server);
gst_rtsp_mount_points_remove_factory(mounts, "/stream");
gst_object_unref(mounts);
g_main_loop_quit(loop);
```

and the stream stops but when I try to init and start stream again it does not start.

Comment: do you recreate the required objects? and what do you mean by it does not start?